# Wrapping C with Python; free(char *) invalid pointer

Tags: python, c, malloc, wrapper, free

I am following  [this](http://intermediate-and-advanced-software-carpentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/c++-wrapping.html) tutorial on wrapping C/C++ with Python.  I have copied the example code verbatim, but will still list it below.

## hello.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>

// Original C Function
char * hello(char * what)
{
    printf("Hello %s!\n", what);
    return what;
}

//  1) Wrapper Function that returns Python stuff
static PyObject * hello_wrapper(PyObject * self, PyObject * args) 
{
  char * input;
  char * result;
  PyObject * ret;

  // parse arguments
  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &input)) {
    return NULL;
  }

  // run the actual function
  result = hello(input);

  // build the resulting string into a Python object.
  ret = PyString_FromString(result);

  free(result);

  return ret;
}
```

The script `hello.c` defines a simple "hello" function, as well as a wrapper which returns a Python object, and (hypothetically) frees the c char * pointer.  **This is where the code fails with the run-time error:** `Error in '/usr/bin/python': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000011fbd44`.  While I believe the error should be limited to this scope, let's go over the rest of the wrapper just in case...

`hello.c` is included in the definition of a module, which allows its methods to be called in Python.  The module is defined as such:

## hellomodule.c

```
#include "hello.c"
#include <Python.h>

// 2) Python module
static PyMethodDef HelloMethods[] =
{
        { "hello", hello_wrapper, METH_VARARGS, "Say hello" },
        { NULL, NULL, 0, NULL }
};

// 3) Module init function
DL_EXPORT(void) inithello(void)
{
    Py_InitModule("hello", HelloMethods);
}
```

Finally, a Python script is implemented to build the module:

## setup.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

# the c++ extension module
extension_mod = Extension("hello", ["hellomodule.c"]) #, "hello.c"])

setup(name = "hello", ext_modules=[extension_mod])
```

Once `setup.py` is run, the module can be imported into any Python script, and its member functions *should* be accessible, and have proven to be, with the exception of the invalid pointer error.  I have spent many hours on this to no avail.  Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/arg.html#PyArg_ParseTuple), pointers produced by `PyArg_ParseTuple()` should not be freed:

> Also, you won’t have to release any memory yourself, except with the es, es#, et and et# formats.

Eliminating the `free(result);` call should stop the crash.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't it `input` that is produced by `PyArg_ParseTuple()` rather than `result`?  after changing the `hello(char * what)` function to return some string other than the input (let's go with "Bears"), I would think that the problem should be fixed, but it has only changed the error to a segmentation fault, still occuring when I free(result).

Comment: It depends on how you are producing that string in the `hello()` function. It should be `free()`d only if you `malloc()`ed it.

Comment: Yep, you are correct.  If the returned string is `malloc()`ed, it must be `free()`d.  Thank you for helping me out!